# Scraping Project Euler site with scrapy

Tags: python, html, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape projecteuler.net with python's scrapy library, just to make practice with it. I've seen online more than one existent implementation of such a scraper, but they seem just too much elaborated for me. I want simply to save the problems (titles, ids, contents) in a json and next loading with ajax in a local webpage on my pc.

I'm implementing my solution that I will terminate anyway, but since I want to discover the smarter way to use the library, I'm asking you to propose the most intelligent programs with scrapy for doing this job (if you want to avoid the json way, and save directly in html... for me may be even better).

This is my first approach (doesn't work):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import httplib2
import requests
import scrapy
from eulerscraper.items import Problem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


def start_urls_detection():
    # su = ['https://projecteuler.net/archives', 'https://projecteuler.net/archives;page=2']
    # i = 1
    #
    # while True:
    #     request = requests.get(su[i])
    #
    #     if request.status_code != 200:
    #         break
    #
    #     i += 1
    #     su.append('https://projecteuler.net/archives;page=' + str(i + 1))

    return ["https://projecteuler.net/"]


class EulerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'euler'
    allowed_domains = ['projecteuler.net']
    start_urls = start_urls_detection()

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        # Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php',), deny=('subsection\.php',))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('problem=\d*',)), callback="parse_problems"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('archives;page=\d*',), unique=True), follow=True)
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        # su = ['https://projecteuler.net/archives', 'https://projecteuler.net/archives;page=2']
        # i = 1
        #
        # while True:
        #     request = requests.get(su[i])
        #
        #     if request.status_code != 200:
        #         break
        #
        #     i += 1
        #     su.append('https://projecteuler.net/archives;page=' + str(i + 1))

        return [scrapy.Request("https://projecteuler.net/archives", self.parse)]

    def parse_problems(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=Problem(), response=response)
        l.add_css("title", "h2")
        l.add_css("id", "#problem_info")
        l.add_css("content", ".problem_content")

        yield l.load_item()

    # def parse_content(self, response):
    #     #return response.css("div.problem_content::text").extract()
    #     next_page = "https://projecteuler.net/archives;page=2"
    #     n = 3
    #
    #     while n < 14:
    #         next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
    #         yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
    #         next_page = next_page[0:len(next_page) - 1] + str(n)
    #         n += 1
```

now I will try with some linkExtractor + manual requests combo. In the meantime, I hopefully wait for your solutions...

Comment: Please read the help file for advice about the kinds of questions that are entertained on StackOverflow.

Comment: You should provide the code you've written in an attempt to solve the problem. Then, if  you experience difficulty with that, ask for assistance with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a simplest yet fitting solution (at least for my purpose), in respect to existent code written to scrape projecteuler:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from eulerscraper.items import Problem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class EulerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'euler'
    allowed_domains = ['projecteuler.net']
    start_urls = ["https://projecteuler.net/archives"]

    def parse(self, response):
        numpag = response.css("div.pagination a[href]::text").extract()
        maxpag = int(numpag[len(numpag) - 1])

        for href in response.css("table#problems_table a::attr(href)").extract():
            next_page = "https://projecteuler.net/" + href
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse_problems)

        for i in range(2, maxpag + 1):
            next_page = "https://projecteuler.net/archives;page=" + str(i)
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse_next)

        return [scrapy.Request("https://projecteuler.net/archives", self.parse)]

    def parse_next(self, response):
        for href in response.css("table#problems_table a::attr(href)").extract():
            next_page = "https://projecteuler.net/" + href
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse_problems)

    def parse_problems(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=Problem(), response=response)
        l.add_css("title", "h2")
        l.add_css("id", "#problem_info")
        l.add_css("content", ".problem_content")

        yield l.load_item()
```

From the start page (archives) I follow every single link to a problem, scraping the data that I need with `parse_problems`. Then I launch the scraper for the other pages of the site, with the same procedure for every list of link.
Also the Item definition with pre and post processes is very clean:

```
import re

import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Compose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags


def extract_first_number(text):
    i = re.search('\d+', text)
    return int(text[i.start():i.end()])


def array_to_value(element):
    return element[0]


class Problem(scrapy.Item):
    id = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, extract_first_number),
        output_processor=Compose(array_to_value)
    )
    title = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags))
    content = scrapy.Field()
```

I launch this with the command `scrapy crawl euler -o euler.json` and it outputs an array of unordered json objects, everyone corrisponding to a single problem: this is fine for me because I'm going to process it with javascript, even if I think resolving the ordering problem via scrapy can be very simple.

EDIT: in fact it is simple, using this pipeline

```
import json

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.list_items = []
        self.file = open('euler.json', 'w')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        ordered_list = [None for i in range(len(self.list_items))]

        self.file.write("[\n")

        for i in self.list_items:
            ordered_list[int(i['id']-1)] = json.dumps(dict(i))

        for i in ordered_list:
            self.file.write(str(i)+",\n")

        self.file.write("]\n")
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.list_items.append(item)
        return item
```

though the best solution may be to create a custom exporter:

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter
from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes


class OrderedJsonItemExporter(JsonItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        # To initialize the object we use JsonItemExporter's constructor
        super().__init__(file)
        self.list_items = []

    def export_item(self, item):
        self.list_items.append(item)

    def finish_exporting(self):
        ordered_list = [None for i in range(len(self.list_items))]

        for i in self.list_items:
            ordered_list[int(i['id'] - 1)] = i

        for i in ordered_list:
            if self.first_item:
                self.first_item = False
            else:
                self.file.write(b',')
                self._beautify_newline()
            itemdict = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(i))
            data = self.encoder.encode(itemdict)
            self.file.write(to_bytes(data, self.encoding))

        self._beautify_newline()
        self.file.write(b"]")
```

and configure it in settings to call it for json:

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'json': 'eulerscraper.exporters.OrderedJsonItemExporter',
}
```