# Invoke scrapy's custom exporter by command line

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline, scrapy-shell

While trying to [resolve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827688/order-a-json-by-field-using-scrapy/48888398#48888398) (output an ordered Json array by a specific item's field), I've [received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48828894/7674438) that suggests me to create a custom exporter for the job.

I'm creating one, but... all the examples that I've find suggest to call it by pipeline, but it seems a bit redundant to me (I've already defined custom behavior on personal exporter... why should I customize with pipeline too?).

What I search is a way to call the custom exporter, once defined, by scrapy shell. For example, to output json I will use:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o myjson.json
```

Does it exists some way to specify *my* custom exporter for writing file in a similar manner? I've found an experimental feature [COMMANDS_MODULE](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#commands-module) for custom commands, but I'm not sure how to link it to my custom exporter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate an exporter by using the [FEED_EXPORTERS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exporters) setting.

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'json': 'path.to.SortedJsonItemExporter',
}
```

Comment: Once you've defined that setting, the custom exporter will be used to export to .json files